# Scala Websocket Client?

Tags: scala, websocket, asynchttpclient

I am looking for a Scala WebSocket client. There are a number of examples, gists and artefacts but most of them don't work (anymore?) and none of them seem to be maintained. A Scala wrapper around AsyncHttpClient would do fine. Thanks for any pointer!

Comment: have you found a suitable solution?

Comment: I think at this point akka-http seems the best choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time has passed and I think [akka-http](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/client-side/websocket-support.html) could be the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the [sttp client](https://github.com/softwaremill/sttp) backends do support WebSockets, see [documentation](https://sttp.softwaremill.com/en/latest/websockets.html).